# Linear regression to correct the colors of RGB images?

Tags: color-correction, rgb

I have several pictures of plants (tif files). Each picture contains a set of Munsell color chips. The "true" RGB values of the Munsell color chips are known. My goal is to correct the colors of the pictures, by comparing the "observed" and the "true" colors of the Munsell color chips.
I tried to use a simple linear regression for each channel.
Here is an example for the Red channel: (EDITED:)

```
x1 = mean_value_of_red_channel_of_observed_color_chip_1
x2 = mean_value_of_red_channel_of_observed_color_chip_2
y1 = red_value_of_true_color_chip_1
y2 = red_value_of_true_color_chip_2
x_mean = (x1+x2)/2
y_mean = (y1+y2)/2
slope = ((x1-x_mean)*(y1-y_mean)+(x2-x_mean)*(y2-y_mean))/((y1-y_mean)^2+(y2-y_mean)^2)
y_intercept = y_mean-(slope*x_mean)
corrected_red_channel_of_image = (slope*red_channel_of_image)+y_intercept
```

The result does not look right:

Original Image
[image: Original Image]
Corrected Image
[image: Corrected Image]

For the conversion I used Python 3.6 with Open CV.
Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: What you did wrong starts with the assumption that color correction is linear, but may include other issues as well...

Comment: @twalberg the sensor is linear in the way it captures light, so it's a reasonable assumption. Problem is that a curve is applied in the raw conversion for gamma and other adjustments.

Comment: It looks like this code will operate on all channels of the image instead of just the red channel?

Comment: do you have the raw files as well?

Comment: Real world objects do not have "true" RGB values (even with scare quotes). It's probably better to use a word like "target" or "expected".

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for the hint! in my script it is right. I edited the code.

Comment: @ths Yes I also have DNG files. Do you think using the DNG files for the color correction could solve the problem?

Comment: I just realized that maybe you're assuming the image is in RGB order when it's actually BGR. I don't know that for a fact but it would explain your result, it's worth checking.

Comment: from the dng you can make a linear gamma tif, apply your corrections and then apply gamma. if that should be the problem.

Comment: @ths Sounds interesting. Do you know how to convert DNG to linear TIF in Photoshop/ Camera Raw? (Should I ask this in a new thread?)

Comment: no but you can do it with dcraw.

Answer (score 1):

With your formula, black (0,0,0) becomes a visible color (y_intercept_R,y_intercept_G,y_intercept_B). Your math are based on wrong assumptions. If the picture is correctly exposed, you have the constraint that 0. gives 0. and 1. (or 100% or 255) gives 1. (or 100% or 255). So your adjustment cannot be linear, it is more like a gamma correction on each channel.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to keep the constraint that 1.=1., but 0=0 is probably a must.

Comment: In my script I added a correction, that sets all negative values to zero and all values higher than 255 to 255. This should not cause the color shifting..